# apic: command not found : Strongloop

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopback

I want to create a Node.js Project with Strongloop,Loopback Framework also i am new to strong loop.I am learning api connect of Strongloop.
But when i am creating project using git bash it throws error **bash: apic: command not found**
Please help.

```
apic loopback project_name
```

But it throws error:

```
bash: apic: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The error statement is clear - in your path is not executable with name "apic".

If apic is allowing running from command line, the "npm install apic -g" will make the apic global, therefore usable anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you should use the slc command instead:

`slc loopback project_name`